# How to find correct hosted agent to build Linux code?

Tags: c++, linux, azure-devops

I am learning VSTS. I have a one-line HelloWorld.cpp file in my repository and a makefile to build this cpp file.

Firstly, I created my build definition, which is like below:
[image]

secondly, I assigned the build definition to the only available Linux hosted-agent, called "Hosted Linux (Preview)":
[image]

After these I kicked off a build but it returns error:
[image]

I then checked the capabilities of the agent. It doesn't have CMake, nor does it have compiler like gcc or clang.
[image]

I checked VSTS documentation pages about build agents, but have no clue what I should do.

Comment: @HarshilLodhi I see your edit but I rolled it back because the edit makes my pictures invisible. If you can edit again without hiding pictures please go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hosted agent and Hosted VS2017 agent have CMake installed, you can use Hosted agent or Hosted VS2017 agent. You need to add the capability manually (cmake and yes), check [Build:CMake Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/cmake#qa).

On the other hand, regarding CMake in Hosted Linux agent, I submit a feedback here: [CMake in Hosted Linux agent](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/152980/cmake-in-hosted-linux-agent.html).

Comment: OK. Thanks. Can Hosted Linux (previewed) agent run make and gcc?

Comment: @Sheen Yes, for example, add Command Line task (Tool:gcc; Argument:--version)